# Xamarin Textview.text = "x" stops execution of the remaining code

Tags: c#, android, user-interface, xamarin

Im trying to fill a collection of textviews, however after setting the first one, the remaining code is not run. And its not because its exiting the loop, because the "var test" is not hit either.
All vars used holds values as expected and no errors are thrown. Im at a loss here on how to debug this or what can be the issue, any tips will be greatly appreciated!

```
           for (int i = 0; i < /*listContent.Count*/9; i++) 
        {
            int listIndex = 0;

            // Find the next "unupdated" tablerow in the collections index.
            for (int j = 0; j < tableRowPool[listContent[i].realCategory].Length; j++)
            {
                if (tableRowPool[listContent[i].realCategory][j].Visibility == ViewStates.Gone)
                {
                    listIndex = j;
                    break;
                }
            }



            tableRowPool[/*listContent[i].realCategory*/ItemCategory.OtherFood][listIndex].Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

            TextView rowItemName = tableRowPool[listContent[i].realCategory][listIndex].GetChildAt(0) as TextView;
            rowItemName.Text = listContent[i].name;
            *****After above line, the rest of the code below is not run.*****

            TextView rowStateEndDate = tableRowPool[listContent[i].realCategory][listIndex].GetChildAt(1) as TextView;
            rowStateEndDate.Text = listContent[i].endDate;

            TextView rowStateAmount = tableRowPool[listContent[i].realCategory][listIndex].GetChildAt(2) as TextView;
            rowStateAmount.Text = listContent[i].amount;

            TextView rowStatePrice = tableRowPool[listContent[i].realCategory][listIndex].GetChildAt(3) as TextView;
            rowStatePrice.Text = listContent[i].price.ToString();

            TextView rowStateDiscountPercent = tableRowPool[listContent[i].realCategory][listIndex].GetChildAt(4) as TextView;
            rowStateDiscountPercent.Text = listContent[i].discountPercent;
        }

        var test = "";
    }
```

Comment: Why the downvote??

Comment: Hi, have you tried use try catch to get the exception?

Answer (score -1):

I just tried ur suggestion and now its working lol, it doesnt even throw an exception or anything it just runs the code as "expected". I should mention though that i just reinstalled visual studio due to another issue, so it could be what fixed it. Anyway, problem is solved now, thanks for your maybe solution, cheers and have a nice weekend!